# How to show Recent Post in blogger without javascript

Tags: xml, blogger

Recent Post Feature good for better experience to visitor i want to show Recent Post to my blogger blog and I able to do this using Json Javascript  but this is not good for SEO. So how do this using xml.

Comment: Its hard, try using lambda operator..